# CSS span among text - fit width/justify

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been searching for the resolution for my problem for quite some time and I can't seem to find any similiar answer.

What I'm trying to do is I'm placing inline spans *(which are at least 300px wide)* among the lines in the block of text and I want them to expand until they, or content in their line reaches parent padding.

I can see this can be a little bit hard to understand, so I have **[this simple graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5215j.jpg)**.

Also, I have **[this Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZJRZLx)**.
I've tried applying following to my span:

```
display: inline-block;
min-width: 300px;
width: 100%;
height: 5px;
```

But **width: 100%** uses parent width, not available width. I don't mind using jQuery, but I'm trying to find pure CSS resolution for now.

I really hope I made myself clear - English isn't my first language.

Thanks in advance;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **jkris**, who gave me a hint about using **flex** property, I've managed to accomplish what I wanted to do by setting

```
display: inline-flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
align-content: flex-start;
```

on the parent element, and setting

```
flex-grow: 1;
```

on filler elements. [**Working Codepen here**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dzjRGZ). Thanks!:)

Answer (score 0):

using just CSS, you can leverage on the flex property. However, this requires you to change your markup to separate out the individual lines. Here's a modified version of your codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BdVEbZ

Your markup would look like so:

```
<div class="karta">
<span class="line">
    Text text text text     
</span>

<span class="line">
<span class="filler"></span> text tt
</span>
<span class="line">
    texttextte <span class="filler"></span>
</span> 
texttexttexttexttext 
<span class="line">
    <span class="filler"></span> .
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah I think I haven't made myself clear - yes, the solution's great, but it doesn't work very well with dynamic content - any other example of text and everything's out of order. Thanks anyway! ;)